# How to get object types to print in raised errors in python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to raise an error that contains the type of some object, like so:

```py
x = 5
raise TypeError(f"Input was type: {type(x)}")
```

However this prints:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[68], line 2
      1 x = 5
----> 2 raise TypeError(f"Input was type: {type(x)}")

TypeError: Input was type:
```

Which does not include the type of the object.

Is there a way to have raised errors print object types?

This is on python 3.11

I have tried both fast string formatting and the `.format()` method, which both don't work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (python 3.11.0), this prints `TypeError: Input was type: <class 'int'>` as you would expect.

Comment: `Cell In[68], line 2` heavily hints at something like JupyterLab, so the issue might come from the environment you are using to display the output. (Although after quick test in JupyterLab, this is still not reproducible)

Comment: Yep it looks like its a VS code Jupyter notebook issue. Works fine outside of VS code.